# AngularJS - Updating data from resolve function (routeProvider)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have an abstract state and other states that inherit from it.

```
state.general (abstract)
   |----------->state.general.list   // It will list a collection
   |
   |-----------state.general.view    // It will display specific element from collection
```

Since several views will use the same data, I was thinking in retrieving the data in the resolve function so it is injectable in both views.

The issue I'm facing is when I'm updating the collection in state.general.view. If I edit an element and go back to the state.general.list state, the collection will not show the data I have edited.

What would be the way to go? I though about init a service in the state.general resolve function and inject this in controllers. How does it sound? Is there any other solution more appropriate?

```
/* CODE */
.state('state.general', 
    {
        abstract: true, 
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: './partials/abstract.html', 
        resolve: {
            collection: function(APIService){
                return APIService.query();
            }
        }
    }
    .state('state.general.list', {
       url: '/list', 
       templateUrl: './partials/list.html',
       controller: function(collection){
           // Do something with collection
       }
    })
    ....
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I do not want to update the whole collection every time I'm going to state state.general.list. In my app the updates can be quite frequent, so downloading the whole collection everytime I go to state.general.list would just not work. For that purpose, I would appreciate ideas/solutions to keep the collection in sync avoiding a full-download.

Comment: We'll need the code for that state implementation

Comment: I guess that the code would be something like that. I have already done changes so I cannot copy/paste anymore. Still... it is just an abstract state...